# Type 'MatchedValue' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

Tags: swift, range, codable

I have a struct that must conform to Codable protocol.
However, I get the error:

> Type 'MatchedValue' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'**

How can I make `String.Index` conform to Codable?
Thanks

```swift
struct MatchedValue: Codable {
    let value: String
    let range: Range<String.Index>
  }
```

Comment: What do you want your encoded JSON to look like?

Comment: Why do you need the Range<String.Index>? can you provide an example of the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Int instead of String.Index.

First, extensions to get the position of an element or string as Int and the ability to use integer ranges:

```swift
extension StringProtocol {
    func distance(of element: Element) -> Int? { firstIndex(of: element)?.distance(in: self) }
    
    func distance<S: StringProtocol>(of string: S) -> Int? { range(of: string)?.lowerBound.distance(in: self) }
    
    func substring(with range: Range<Int>) -> String? {
        guard range.lowerBound >= 0 && range.upperBound <= self.count else { return nil }
        
        let lowerBoundStringIndex = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)
        let upperBoundStringIndex = self.index(lowerBoundStringIndex, offsetBy: range.upperBound - range.lowerBound)

        return String(self[lowerBoundStringIndex..<upperBoundStringIndex])
    }

    subscript(r: Range<Int>) -> String? { substring(with: r) }
    
    func substring(with range: ClosedRange<Int>) -> String? {
        guard range.lowerBound >= 0 && range.upperBound < self.count else { return nil }
        
        if range.lowerBound == range.upperBound { return "" }
        
        let lowerBoundStringIndex = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)
        let upperBoundStringIndex = self.index(lowerBoundStringIndex, offsetBy: range.upperBound + 1 - range.lowerBound)

        return String(self[lowerBoundStringIndex..<upperBoundStringIndex])
    }
    
    subscript(r: ClosedRange<Int>) -> String? { substring(with: r) }
}

extension Collection {
    func distance(to index: Index) -> Int { distance(from: startIndex, to: index) }
}

extension String.Index {
    func distance<S: StringProtocol>(in string: S) -> Int { string.distance(to: self) }
}
```

Now you can use this new implementation:

```swift
let letters = "My string"
letters.count // 9

// get range
let lowerBound: Int? = letters.distance(of: "M")
let upperBound: Int? = letters.distance(of: "g")
let intRange: Range<Int> = lowerBound!..<upperBound!
let intClosedRange: ClosedRange<Int> = lowerBound!...upperBound!

// get substring
letters.substring(with: intRange)           // "My strin"
letters.substring(with: intClosedRange)     // "My string"
// or
letters[intRange]                           // "My strin"
letters[intClosedRange]                     // "My string"
```

I also include a comparison using String.Index and other tests.

```swift
// For comparison purposes only
let lowerIndex = letters.firstIndex(of: "M")
let upperIndex = letters.firstIndex(of: "g")
let range: Range<String.Index> = lowerIndex!..<upperIndex!
let closedRange: ClosedRange<String.Index> = lowerIndex!...upperIndex!
letters[range]                              // "My strin"
letters[closedRange]                        // "My string"

// Additional implementation tests
letters.substring(with: 3...5)  // "str"
letters.substring(with: 3..<5)  // "st"
letters.substring(with: 0...9)  // nil
letters.substring(with: 0..<9)  // "My string"
letters.substring(with: 2...2)  // ""
letters.substring(with: 2..<2)  // ""
```

Here is my
[gist](https://gist.github.com/Carrione/2ab54e470885815b6d361b469769cdaa).

Comment: `Range` _does_ conform to `Codable` if `Bound` does

Comment: @JoakimDanielson You're right. Thank you for the warning.

Comment: I completely changed my original answer.